# How to avoid hashes in font-family in NextJs 13 using localFont()?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I've created NextJS 13 project and added local font to the RootLayout using localFont().

```
const roboto = localFont({
    src: [
        {
            path: '../themes/fonts/Roboto400.woff2',
            weight: '400',
            style: 'normal',
        },
        {
            path: '../themes/fonts/Roboto700.woff2',
            weight: '700',
            style: 'normal',
        }
    ]
});
```

And connected it as a classname:

```
<body suppressHydrationWarning={true} className={roboto.className}>
    {children}
</body>
```

But when I checked the body element's font family, I found that it uses hashes:

```
.__className_9f4694 {
    font-family: '__roboto_9f4694', '__roboto_Fallback_9f4694';
}
```

How to avoid hashes and have something like this:

```
.__className_9f4694 {
    font-family: 'Roboto, sans-serif';
}
```

I've tried some approaches:

1. to move all 'font-faces' to global.css and fonts(.woff, .woff2) to the project folder. It's easy and solves the problem with hashes and usage.
2. since I'm trying to use 'styled-components', I've put all the 'font-faces' to createGlobalStyle and all fonts(.woff, .woff2) in the [public](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing#static-assets) folder. It solves the problem with hashes and usage.

But I'm still wondering how to do it via localFont().